# Fetching requests in queue concurrently

Tags: python, python-asyncio, httpx

I have written code that allows me to start fetching the next chunk of data from an API while the previous chunk of data is being processed.

I'd like this to be always fetching **up to** 5 chunks concurrently at any given moment, but the returned data should always be processed in the correct order even if a request that is last in the queue completes before any other.

How can my code be changed to make this happen?

```py
class MyClient:
    async def fetch_entities(
        self,
        entity_ids:List[int],
        objects:Optional[List[str]],
        select_inbound:Optional[List[str]]=None,
        select_outbound:Optional[List[str]]=None,
        queue_size:int=5,
        chunk_size:int=500,
    ):
        """
        Fetch entities in chunks

        While one chunk of data is being processed the next one can
        already be fetched. In other words: Data processing does not
        block data fetching.
        """
        objects = ",".join(objects)
        if select_inbound:
            select_inbound = ",".join(select_inbound)

        if select_outbound:
            select_outbound = ",".join(select_outbound)

        queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=queue_size)

        # TODO: I want to be able to fill the queue with requests that are already executing

        async def queued_chunks():
            for ids in chunks(entity_ids, chunk_size):
                res = await self.client.post(urllib.parse.quote("entities:fetchdata"), json={
                    "entityIds": ids,
                    "objects": objects,
                    "inbound": {
                        "linkTypeIds": select_outbound,
                        "objects": objects,
                    } if select_inbound else {},
                    "outbound": {
                        "linkTypeIds": select_inbound,
                        "objects": objects,
                    } if select_outbound else {},
                })
                await queue.put(res)
            await queue.put(None)

        asyncio.create_task(queued_chunks())

        while True:
            res = await queue.get()
            if res is None:
                break
            res.raise_for_status()
            queue.task_done()
            for entity in res.json():
                yield entity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d use two queues here: one with the chunks to process, and one for the chunks that are complete. You can have any number of worker tasks to process chunks, and you can put a size limit on the first queue to limit how many chunks you prefetch. Use just a single loop to receive the processed chunks, to ensure they are kept ordered (your code already does this).

The trick is to put [*futures*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) into both queues, one for every chunk to be processed. The worker tasks that do the processing fetch a chunk and future pair, and then need to resolve the associated future by setting the POST response as the result of these futures. The loop that handles the processed chunks awaits on each future and so will only proceed to the next chunk when the current chunk has been fully processed. For this to work you need to put both the chunk *and* the corresponding future into the first queue for the workers to process. Put the *same* future into the second queue; these enforce the chunk results are processed in order.

So, in summary:

- Have two queues:

  1. `chunks` holds `(chunk, future)` objects.
  2. `completed` holds futures, *the same futures paired with chunks in the other queue.
- Create “worker” tasks that consume from the chunks queue. If you create 5, then 5 chunks will be processed in parallel. Every time a worker has competed processing, they set the result on the corresponding future.
- use a “processed chunks” loop; it takes the next future from the `completed` queue and awaits on it. Only when the *specific* chunk associated with that future  has been competed will it produce the result (set by a worker task).

As a rough sketch, it’d look something like this:

```
chunk_queue = asyncio.Queue()
completed_queue = asyncio.Queue()
WORKER_COUNT = queue_size

async def queued_chunks():
    for ids in chunks(entity_ids, chunk_size):
        future = asyncio.Future()
        await chunk_queue.put((ids, future))
        await completed_queue.put(future)
    completed_queue.put(None)

async def worker():
    while True:
        ids, future = chunk_queue.get()
        try:
            res = await self.client.post(urllib.parse.quote("entities:fetchdata"), json={
                "entityIds": ids,
                "objects": objects,
                "inbound": {
                    "linkTypeIds": select_outbound,
                    "objects": objects,
                } if select_inbound else {},
                "outbound": {
                    "linkTypeIds": select_inbound,
                    "objects": objects,
                } if select_outbound else {},
            })
            res.raise_for_status()
            future.set_result(res)
        except Exception as e:
            future.set_exception(e)
            return

workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker) for _ in range(WORKER_COUNT)]
chunk_producer = asyncio.create_task(queued_chunks())

try:
    while True:
        future = await completed_queue.get()
        if future is None:
            # all chunks have been processed!
            break
        res = await future
        yield from res.json()

finally:
    for w in workers:
        w.cancel()
    asyncio.wait(workers)
```

If you must limit how many chunks are *queued* (and not just how many are being processed concurrently), set `maxsize` on the `chunk_queue` queue (to a value greater than `WORKER_COUNT`). Use this to limit memory requirements, for example.

However, if you were to set the `maxsize` to a value *equal* to `WORKER_COUNT`, you may as well get rid of the worker tasks altogether and instead put the body of the worker loop as coroutines wrapped in tasks into the completed results queue. The asyncio `Task` class is a subclass of `Future`, which automatically sets the future result when the coroutine it wraps completes. If you are not going to put in more chunks into the `chunk_queue` than you have worker tasks you may as well cut out the middleman, drop the `chunk_queue` altogether. The tasks then go into the completed queue instead of plain futures:

```py
completed_queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=queue_size)

async def queued_chunks():
    for ids in chunks(entity_ids, chunk_size):
        task = asyncio.create_task(fetch_task(ids))
        await completed_queue.put(task)
    completed_queue.put(None)

async def fetch_task(ids):
    res = await self.client.post(urllib.parse.quote("entities:fetchdata"),
        json={
            "entityIds": ids,
            "objects": objects,
            "inbound": {
                "linkTypeIds": select_outbound,
                "objects": objects,
            } if select_inbound else {},
            "outbound": {
                "linkTypeIds": select_inbound,
                "objects": objects,
            } if select_outbound else {},
        }
    )
    res.raise_for_status()
    return res

chunk_producer = asyncio.create_task(queued_chunks())

while True:
    task = await completed_queue.get()
    if task is None:
        # all chunks have been processed!
        break
    res = await task
    yield from task.json()
```

This version is really close to what you had already, the only difference being that we put the await for the client POST coroutine and the check for the response status code into a separate coroutine to be run as tasks. You could also make the `self.client.post()` coroutine into the task (so *not* await on it) and leave checking for the response status to the final queue processing loop. That’s what [Pablo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65711296) proposed so I won’t repeat that here.

Note that this version *starts the task before putting it in the queue*. The queue was a not the only limit on the number of active tasks, there is also an already started task waiting for space to be put into the queue on one end (the line `await completed_queue.put(task)` blocks if the queue is full), and another task already taken out by the queue consumer (fetched by `task = await completed_queue.get()`). If you need to limit the number of active tasks, subtract 2 from the queue maxsize to set an upper limit.

Also, because tasks could complete in the meantime, there could be `maxsize + 1` *fewer* **active** tasks, but you can’t start any more until more space has been freed in the queue. Because the first approach queues *inputs* for tasks, it hasn’t got these issues. You *could* mitigate this problem by using a [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#semaphore) rather than a bound queuesize to limit tasks (acquire a slot before starting a task, and just before returning from a task, releasing a slot).

Personally I’d pick my first proposal as it gives you separate control over concurrency and chunk prefetching, without the issues the second approach has.

Comment: Following your second approach, I have to set `maxsize` of the queue to 3 in order to get a queue size of 5. Any idea why that is? How would I get an actual `maxsize` of 3?

Comment: @demux the second approach **starts the task before putting it in the queue**, plus the consumer will remove at least one item almost immediately. So if you limit the queue to 3 items, then you start a task, push it in, and then the other end picks up the task and waits for it to compete. In the meantime you start a further 3 tasks and push them into the queue, and then start a fifth task, and then the queue blocks. The queue limits what can be pushed in, not how many tasks you can start.

Comment: @demux the first approach limits tasks by explicitly creating concurrent workers; the queue is a means of getting the input (`ids`) to the workers. So the work to fetch a chunk result won’t start unless a worker is available. For the second approach you would have to rate limit the chunks, before creating tasks. That could be done with a [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#semaphore) as the limiter rather than set a maximum queue size.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of awaiting the coroutine before you enqueue it, just enqueue the coroutine and await it later

```
class MyClient:
async def fetch_entities(
    self,
    entity_ids:List[int],
    objects:Optional[List[str]],
    select_inbound:Optional[List[str]]=None,
    select_outbound:Optional[List[str]]=None,
    queue_size:int=5,
    chunk_size:int=500,
):
    """
    Fetch entities in chunks

    While one chunk of data is being processed the next one can
    already be fetched. In other words: Data processing does not
    block data fetching.
    """
    objects = ",".join(objects)
    if select_inbound:
        select_inbound = ",".join(select_inbound)

    if select_outbound:
        select_outbound = ",".join(select_outbound)

    queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=queue_size)

    # TODO: I want to be able to fill the queue with requests that are already executing

    async def queued_chunks():
        for ids in chunks(entity_ids, chunk_size):
            cor = self.client.post(urllib.parse.quote("entities:fetchdata"), json={
                "entityIds": ids,
                "objects": objects,
                "inbound": {
                    "linkTypeIds": select_outbound,
                    "objects": objects,
                } if select_inbound else {},
                "outbound": {
                    "linkTypeIds": select_inbound,
                    "objects": objects,
                } if select_outbound else {},
            })
            task = asyncio.create_task(cor)
            await queue.put(cor)
        await queue.put(None)

    asyncio.create_task(queued_chunks())

    while True:
        task = await queue.get()
        if task is None:
            break
        res = await task
        res.raise_for_status()
        queue.task_done()
        for entity in res.json():
            yield entity
```

Comment: As noted in my answer: this approach starts tasks before putting them into the queue. There will be a task waiting to be put into the queue on the producer end, as well as an active task fetched by the consumer end. If the maxsize is 5 that means there will be between 1 and 7 active tasks at any one time; the task on the consumer end blocks the consumer loop while active, and the other 6 tasks (5 in the queue, 1 waiting for an empty slot), could all have completed in the meantime. If this is an issue, queue chunks instead and use worker tasks, or use a semaphore.